# How to order two SELECTs with a UNION by a column I'm not selecting?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, mariadb

This query works:

```
 SELECT recipient_id FROM messages WHERE (sender_id=? and folder=1) 
   UNION 
     SELECT sender_id FROM messages WHERE (recipient_id=? and folder=1)
```

but I need to `ORDER BY time DESC` and wherever I add that it doesn't work. If I add `, time` to what I'm selecting it will order correctly, but it will change what it returns.

I'm using MariaDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a subselect over your union ordered result set and select only the desired field

```
SELECT id FROM (
SELECT recipient_id as id,time  FROM messages WHERE (sender_id=? and folder=1)
 UNION 
SELECT sender_id as id,time  FROM messages WHERE (recipient_id=? and folder=1)
ORDER BY time DESC
) t
```

Or if you want to distinguish what type of id is either a sender or receiver you do so

```
SELECT id,`type` FROM (
SELECT recipient_id as id,time, 'recipient' as `type`  FROM messages WHERE (sender_id=? and folder=1)
 UNION 
SELECT sender_id as id,time ,'sender' as `type`  FROM messages WHERE (recipient_id=? and folder=1)
ORDER BY time DESC
) t
```

Comment: what is the `t` at the end for?

Comment: It's needed to give the temporary (inner) table from which you're selecting a name.

Comment: When ever you use a subselect and selects data from it then you need give an alais to your subselect so i have used t as alias for the subselect

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this works with MySql, but it would work with Oracle:

```
SELECT id,max(time) FROM (
SELECT recipient_id as id,time  FROM messages WHERE (sender_id=? and folder=1)
UNION 
SELECT sender_id as id,time  FROM messages WHERE (recipient_id=? and folder=1)
) t group by id
order by 2 desc
```

Of course their are more efficient ways, maybe another group by into the parts of the union.

Answer (score 0):

The `UNION` set operator will remove duplicate rows; if the SELECT returns multiple rows with the same recipient_id, those will be collapsed into a single row. You'd need to decide which row you want the `time` value from.

The `UNION ALL` set operator is similar to `UNION`, in that it concatenates the results, but it doesn't remove "duplicate" rows.

You could get an equivalent result with a query something like this:

```
SELECT IF(m.sender_id=?,m.recipient_id,IF(m.recipient_id=?,m.sender_id,NULL)) AS x_id
  FROM messages m
 WHERE m.folder = 1
   AND (sender_id=? OR recipient_id=?)
 GROUP BY x_id
 ORDER BY MAX(m.time) DESC
```

(NOTE: this will order the `x_id` values by the latest `time` value.)

If you don't really want to eliminate duplicates (which the `UNION` operator is doing in the original query), if you want to return all of the rows, remove the `GROUP BY` clause and use a scalar `time` in place of the aggregate in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT IF(m.sender_id=?,m.recipient_id,IF(m.recipient_id=?,m.sender_id,NULL)) AS x_id
  FROM messages m
 WHERE m.folder = 1
   AND (sender_id=? OR recipient_id=?)
 ORDER BY m.time DESC
```